# Possible to dump the contents of the session onto the screen?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to dump the contents of session or what is in the params onto the page for debugging information?  If so, how do you do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `debug` method in your views to pretty print the value.

```
<%= debug params %>
<%= debug session %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DebugHelper.html

Answer (score 3):

Use this to see the session

```
logger.info session.inspect
```

You should be able to see the parameters in the server log by default...